# Style Property inside a Class in JavaScript is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, css

```
let taskList = document.getElementById("taskList");
const newItem = new Item("some value");
taskList.append(newItem.item)

const updateTaskList = () => {
    taskList.innerHTML = "";
    taskItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = taskItems;
    taskItems = div.querySelectorAll("li");
    taskItems.forEach((task) => {
    taskList.append(new Item("some value").item);
    })    
}

const updateLocal = () => {
    taskList = document.getElementById("taskList");
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(taskList.innerHTML));
}

class Item {
    constructor(name){
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = name;
        this.item = div;
        this.item.addEventListener("click", () => this.changeStyle());
    }

    changeStyle(){
        this.item.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        updateLocal();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    updateTaskList();
})
```

The style gets updated in the DOM, but after reloading the page the style disappears instead of getting stored locally. What's the problem here.

Comment: When the page reloads is the localStorage correct?

Comment: when do you call the method changeStyle ?

Comment: Could you please add some HTML?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes, the tasks that I add from the HTML do get stored in my localStorage, it's just that the styling associated does not change.

Comment: @jeremy-denis I'm calling it with a click event listener. I forgot to add it, I've edited and added it in the class constructor now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I was creating a new element from the Class, and not updating the style.
All I had to do was pass in the styles from the local storage to the class, and update the styles for the new element.

```
class Item {
constructor(name, styles){
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = name;
    if(styles) div.styles.textDecoration = styles.textDecoration;
    this.item = div;
    this.item.addEventListener("click", () => this.changeStyle());
}

changeStyle(){
    this.item.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    updateLocal();
}
```

}